# .NET MVC ViewBag Model Filtering in view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

i'm tryng to pass a model collection in a ViewBag var and then filter it in the view bag, but i get the error.

"Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type"

in the controller i have the next code

```
List<PersonalModel> Personal = new List<PersonalModel>();
Personal = db.Personal.ToList();
ViewBag.Personal = Personal;
```

And in my view i want to do something like this

```
@{
        var personal = ViewBag.Personal;
        personal=personal.Where(s => s.ID == @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) ).FirstOrDefault();
        @personal.FullName
}
```

I want to use the id that i have loaded in the model of my view, to display just the FullName in the model, but is not working. Any suggestions?, thanks.

Comment: If it is a dynamic, why don't you just cast it on the view side?
var personal = (List<PersonalModel>)ViewBag.Personal;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just confirmed, cast the dynamic when you grab it on the view side and you should be able to work with it as expected:

```
List<someObject> someSet = new List<someObject>();
dynamic dynamicSet = someSet;

// this will error because you cant perform lambda expressions on a dynamic
dynamicSet.Select(a => a.se == false);

// this will work because it is now casted into the structure you want and can work with
var newSet = (List<string>)dynamicSet;
newSet.Select(a => a.se == false);
```

Comment: Excellent, i only had to use the correct objects and worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a nice code.. you should not place your logic into the View